# CPLEX - getting minimum of a set of variables over a condition

Tags: cplex

I have to solve the following problem using CPLEX Java API:

I need to write a condition that will return a minimum of a set of integer variables (let's say x[i], i=1,2,...,n) but considering only the positive ones.

In other words:

min{x[i] | x[i]>0}

I know that CPLEX has the minimum function, but the problem is how to pass it the mentioned condition.

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? What are you trying to do with this? Use  the value of min{x[i] | x[i]>0} in a constraint or objective?

Comment: Actually by "return" I mean assigning the result to the auxiliary variable which appears in other constraints. Let's say there is a condition y = min{x[i] | x[i]>0} and there is another one: y+1 < z.

Answer (score 2):

Create a single continuous variable. Add constraints that this new variable must be <= all of the integer variables. Then just maximise the continuous variable.

Answer (score 1):

TimChippingtonDerrick's answer is missing the non-negativity constraint for the continuous variable. Moreover, that method does not accommodate the OP's original objective function.

An (expensive) way of doing this is to introduce additional binary variables, one for each integer variable and write big M constraints:

```
x[i] >= y >= x[i] - M(1-z[i])

SUM(i,z[i]) = 1
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit your approach?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create expression to use min function in cplex
this is example to chose minimum value between two value to be greater than 0.3

```
IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
            IloNumVar x1 = cplex.numVar(0.1, Double.MAX_VALUE, "x1");
            IloNumVar x2 = cplex.numVar(0.2, Double.MAX_VALUE, "x2");
IloLinearNumExpr y=cplex.linearNumExpr() ;
            cplex.addGe(cplex.min(x1, x2),0.3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In OPL CPLEX I would write

```
int n=10;

dvar int x[1..n];

dvar int m;

subject to
{
  m==min(i in 1..n) maxl(0,x[i]);

}
```

but you could do the same with java